# Minify everything into one file or use CDN

Tags: javascript

For things like jQuery etc, isit better to leave it to use CDN or minify it into 1 file together with other JS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CDN - it's likely it will already be cached on the users machines and thus you'll save the download for it. Not to mention it will load faster from a CDN than from your site anyway - the overhead of the one extra connection to grab that file is diminimus

Comment: While I agree with "the overhead of the one extra connection to grab that file is diminimus"...you're making a very bad assumption there, that is is **one** file, the OP is taking about *many* files, and whether they should be combined.  You have to look at how many round-trips you're adding by not combining.

Comment: @Nick, that's true. I assumed by his "things like jQuery etc" he was meaning big often used frameworks, and I think for the most part there aren't too many that it would make sense to combined them all. But you're right, it's definitely not a one size fits all solution - it's case by case.

Comment: @NickCraver so if I had the choice to use a CDN for jQuery and FontAwesome do it.  But for all my jQuery plugins, such as: jquery.form, jquery.validate, jquery.fancybox, etc; It would be better to concat the minified versions into one file, or go with CDN like CDNjs that has them all?

Answer (score 1):

All your code should definitely be combined & minified. For the libraries, it's a bit trickier. CDNs are good in theory, but some studies have shown that they were not actually as efficient as they could be because of various reasons.

That means, if you've 50% miss rate on your CDN, the overhead of the extra DNS resolving and extra connection can actually slow you down more than it'll help.

The most important thing anyway is that you should version your minified/combined JS file, make it have a unique url for every version of the code you deploy. That way you can set Expires headers to +10 years, and make sure that anyone that downloads it only downloads it once.

Also don't forget to enable gzip (mod_deflate in apache), that will typically compress the transfer to 1/5-1/10th of its original size.

Answer (score 0):

Using CDN is great, as the js file may be already cached from the CDN to user's computer.

But, there might be some plugins of jQuery and your own sites validation and other functions which might be separated in different JS files. then minify + combining is good approach.

For our ease we have separated the code in different files, and when browser tries to load content it has limitations on how many requests to send on the same server,  CDN is out of your domain it will be requested without any browser limit so it loads fast. You need to combine your js files to reduce the number of requests from browser to load your page faster.

For me I use PHP to combine and minify

In html

`<script src="js.php" >`

and in php

> header('Content-type: text/javascript');
>
> include 'js/plugin.js';
>
> include 'js/validation.js';

You can use `output buffering` to minify and also send this content as gziped to browser